# What is the best way to create a composed object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to create a composed object with this kind of behaviour :

```
page = MinimalistCms::Page.create
page.test #return undefined method
page.parts.create!(title: 'test', body: 'test')
page.test #return 'test'
page.test = 'a body'
page.test #return 'a body'
```

To do this, I created this class :

```
module PartComposition
  def self.included(model_class)
    model_class.class_eval do
      has_many :parts, class_name: 'PagePart'
    end
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    title = name.to_s.downcase.underscore
    if title.end_with?('=')
      return update_part(title, args.first)
    else
      part = find_part(title)
      if part
        return part.body
      else
        super(name, *args)
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def update_part(title, attribute)
    part = find_part(title.chop)
    return part.update_attribute(:body, attribute)
  end

  def find_part(title)
    parts.with_globalize(title: title).first
  end
end
```

It works but when I do this `page.body = 'test'` it save automaticaly the record. I'm not sure it's the best way.

The first time, page.test should return undefined method. To create a part should create a new virtual attribute. The attribute should work exactly as a normal attribute.

Do you ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to save the part just do `part.body = attribute` instead of `part.update_attribute`. You can then have an instance variable `dirty_parts` that holds a list of unsaved parts, and when issuing a `save` or `save!` you can save the parts and call `super`, or put `autosave` in the parts relationship.

Anyway, I like the way it is now.

Comment: sorry, I had a mistake in my comments. The first time, page.test should return undefined method. To create a part should create a new virtual attribute. I edit my question.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the lack of understanding of your question. Can't contribute too much so, but changed my answer.